# I am trying to serialize multiple objects and i could quite get pass the error of trying to add values to may ArrayList (Book)

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization

in the line of books.add it says incompatible types: string cannot be converted to Author
I tried converting it all to string but it still didn't work. My problem is how do i make the string be converted to author. The expected output of this is to simply create an arraylist of 5 books with the class of authors, books, and publishing dat. Under the Book class, i am trying to add the arraylist but i cannot seem to get pass the problem of the string to be converting to the object author.

```
public class Book {
    private String bookTitle;
    private Author name;
    private PubDate date;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String bookTitle, Author name, PubDate date) {
        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getBookTitle() {
        return bookTitle;
    }

    public Author getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public PubDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setBookTitle(String bookTitle) {
        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    }

    public void setName(Author name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDate(PubDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book{" + "bookTitle=" + bookTitle + ", name=" + name + ", date=" + date + '}';
    }

  

}
```

```
public class Author {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String title;

    public Author() {
    }

    public Author(String firstname, String lastname, String title) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Author{" + "firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", title=" + title + '}';
    }

}
```

```
public class Serialization {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
        ArrayList<PubDate> pubs = new ArrayList<PubDate>();
        
       
        
        books.add(new Book("Book Title", "Author Name", "Publishing Date"));
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You defined your Book constructor as taking the 3 arguments `String bookTitle, Author name, PubDate date)`, but you are trying to pass 3 Strings into it. That can't work. If you designed your class constructor to take an Object of type `Author` and `PubDate` then that is what you have to pass into that constructor. Either change your call or change your constructor (or add a new one) to accept the arguments you pass into it.

Comment: " how do i make the string be converted to author" <- FYI, you do not "convert" a String to an Author. You create an Author Object by calling the constructor you defined. eG `Author myAuthor = new Author("authorFirstname", "authorLastname", "authorTitle");` and then you can use that created Object to pass it into the Book class.

Comment: rephrase ur title, its unclear